# How to mock Java static block

Tags: java, kotlin, static, mockk

I have a following Java class in a 3rd party library:

```java
public final class SomeFactory {
  public static native someMethod1()
  public static native someMethod2()

  private SomeFactory() {
  }

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("some_lib");
  }
}
```

And this crashes my tests, because loading that `some_lib` fails.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no some_lib in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
```

So how can I mock this class? I'm suing MockK and Kotest.

I've tried different combinations of just `mockk()`, `mockkStatic()`, `mockkConstructor()` and others, but nothing works. I've even tried `mockkStatic(System::class)`, but it seems like it broke the JVM completely.

Comment: "I've even tried mockkStatic(System::class), but it seems like it broke the JVM completely." That seems reasonable, yes. :D

Comment: But to actually help: Instead of mocking the 3rd party library class, can you mock the class that is using it? You can encapsulate the use of this class in another that you wrote yourself, preferably moving the initialization to somewhere that's not dependent on class loading order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was create a new object, that wraps the original one:

```kotlin
object SomeWrapper {
  fun someMethod1() = SomeFactory.someMethod1()
}
```

and then in MockK, just mock the object:

```kotlin
mockkObject(SomeWrapper)
every { SomeWrapper.method1() } returns mockk()
```